# Calculate Radius of Curvature

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting, parametric-functions

I have a list of coordinates that make a near-parabolic graph, which I managed to fit and calculate the curvature. However, the curvature only outputs a equation. Is there any way to calculate the radius of the curvature so it gives a numeric value? Any help is appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```
list = {{54.5, 120.5}, {65.25, 143.15}, {65.61, 143.02}, {76.18, 
    157.28}, {89.89, 176.76}, {98.08, 184.87}, {98.33, 
    184.44}, {118.5, 197.5}, {140.77, 205.74}, {150.96, 
    207.06}, {163.11, 206.07}, {169.09, 204.77}, {177.07, 
    202.8}, {181.14, 201.13}, {182.41, 200.47}, {194.65, 
    192.49}, {201.47, 188.95}, {209.02, 182.56}, {209.21, 
    182.86}, {222.11, 172.77}, {230.93, 161.53}, {230.96, 
    161.51}, {245.51, 141.75}, {257.03, 124.18}, {257.23, 
    124.53}, {261.71, 114.96}, {261.72, 114.91}, {267.16, 
    104.41}, {267.29, 104.07}, {280.45, 72.62}, {280.63, 
    72.34}, {283.35, 63.57}, {286.5, 48.5}};

fit = NonlinearModelFit[list, a*(x + c)^2 + b, {a, b, c}, x];
curvature = Simplify[ArcCurvature[{t, fit[t]}, t]]
```

The fitted equation along with the list of coordinates graphed out:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Curvature of a parabola depends on the position. To find curvature at the maximum point do

```
ArcCurvature[{t,fit[t]},t]/.Maximize[fit[t],t][[2]]
(*0.0170112*)
```

Comment: Also find max curvature with `Maximize[curvature, t]` giving `{0.00193965, {t -> 48.421}}` and min curvature on the range xmin, xmax with `{xmin, xmax} = 
 MinMax[list[[All, 1]]]; Minimize[{curvature, xmin <= t <= xmax}, t]` giving `{0.00114411, {t -> 286.5}}`

Comment: @flinty Thank you, I also notice your answer on a related post.

Comment: Yes it's very similar. I forgot to constrain the Maximize too, it should be `Maximize[{curvature, xmin <= t <= xmax}, t]` giving `{0.0170112, {t -> 154.442}}` which is the same as your value.